# In a version of Einstein's thought experiment about a burst of photons in a box, how do we obtain the equation $mL+M\Delta x=0$?

Tags: special-relativity

I am reading the book "Special Relativity" by A.P. French. In the first chapter, there is a section that talks about a version of a thought experiment invented by Einstein in 1906.

> The purpose of it is to suggest that energy must have associated with
> it a certain inertial mass equivalent. We suppose that an amount $E$
> of radiant energy (a burst of photons) is emitted from one end of a
> box of mass M and length L that is isolated from its surroundings and
> is initially stationary [Fig. 1-4(a)]. The radiation carries momentum
> $E/c$. Since the total momentum of the system remains equal to zero,
> the box must acquire a momentum equal to $-E/c$. Hence the box recoils
> with a speed $v$ given by
>
> $$v=-\frac{E}{Mc}\tag{1-5}$$
>
> After traveling freely for  time $\Delta t$ ($=L/c$ very nearly,
> provided $v<<c$), the radiation hits the other end of the box and
> conveys an impulse, equal and opposite to the one it gave initially,
> which brings the box to rest again. Thus the result of the process is
> to move the box through a distance $\Delta x$:
>
> $$\Delta x=v\Delta t=-\frac{EL}{Mc^2}\tag{1-6}$$
>
> But this being an isolated system, we are reluctant to believe that
> the center of mass of the box plus its contents has moved. We
> therefore postulate that the radiation has carried with it the
> equivalent of a mass $m$, such that
>
> $$mL+M\Delta x = 0\tag{1-7}$$

My question is about equation (1-7).

As far as my calculations go, the sign in that expression should be negative. The depiction below shows the box (in light blue) initially and after the radiation has hit the other side of the box and brought it to a stop again).

[image]

We start with a system composed of a mass $m$ at the origin and a mass $M-m$ at a point $x_{cm,i}$. The latter is the initial center of mass of the box without the mass $m$ which will become radiant energy.

The initial center of mass of the system is

$$x_{cm,sys,i}=\frac{m\cdot 0+(M-m)x_{cm,i}}{M}$$

and the center of mass after the radiation hits the other end and the box stops again is

$$x_{cm,sys,f}=\frac{m\cdot (L-\Delta x)+(M-m)(x_{cm,i}-\Delta x)}{M}$$

Since the center of mass of the system does not change we have

$$x_{cm,sys,i}=x_{cm,sys,f}$$

$$\frac{m\cdot 0+(M-m)x_{cm,i}}{M}=\frac{m\cdot (L-\Delta x)+(M-m)(x_{cm,i}-\Delta x)}{M}$$

$$m(L-\Delta x)-(M-m)\Delta x = 0$$

$$mL-M\Delta x = 0$$

Where does the positive sign come from in (1-7)? In other words, is there a sign error in my derivation or is there some convention being used somewhere?